# Winforms Data Binding to Custom Class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to bind some Winform objects to a custom class, more specifically an instance of my custom class which I have added to the Form in the code.  C#, .NET 2010 Express.

For example, here is a fragment of the class, and the UserInfoForm

```
public class UserInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name = "DefaultName";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool showTutorial = true;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public enum onCloseEvent = LastWindowClosedEvent.Exit;
}

public enum LastWindowClosedEvent
{
    MainMenu, 
    Exit, 
    RunInBackground
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserInfo userToBind = new UserInfo();

    TextBox TB_userName = new TextBox();
    CheckBox CB_showTutorial = new CheckBox();
    ComboBox DDB_onCloseEvent = new ComboBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to bind the values of these form controls to their respective value in userToBind, but have had no luck.  All the tutorials I can find are either way out of date (2002), or about binding controls to a dataset, or other type of database.

I am obviously overlooking something, but I haven't figured out what.

Thank you very much for any info you can share.

More info: UserInfo is designed to be XML-friendly so it can be saved as a user profile.  UserInfo will contain other custom XML classes, all nested under the UserInfo, and many controls will only need to access these child classes.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [DataBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) property of your controls (textbox, checkbox...) to add a binding to a specific control. For instance:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TB_userName.DataBindings.Add("Text", userToBind, "name");
}
```

Also, IIRC, data binding only works on [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so you'll first need to modify your `UserInfo` class accordingly. Moreover, if you want the UI to update automatically when modifying your objects in code, you must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) in your custom classes.

Comment: I also found that the properties need to be public, internal did not work for me.

Comment: This is an old post, but if someone winds up here, it is worth noting that you can now avoid the static strings in databinding -
TB_userName.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TB_username.Text), userToBind, nameof(userToBind.name));